# How to display null value when fk is null

Tags: mysql, null

I have a MySQL table that has two fk referencing to another table

type1 cannot be null, but type2 can be. Both are fk to the *M_TYPE* table

```
Katachi
*Id         int
name        varchar(40)
-type1      int
-type2      int
```

```
M_TYPE
*Id         int 
type_name   varchar(40)
```

I made a query to display the *katachi* table, but instead of the type number I want it to display the *type_name*

```
select 
    k.name, 
    t1.type_name as type1, 
    t2.type_name as type2
from katachi k, m_type t1, m_type t2
where k.type1=t1.id and k.type2=t2.id;
```

It displays the katachi with 2 types, but when it comes to katachi with one type and second as null it ignores it.

So I changed the code to this

```
select 
    k.name, 
    t1.type_name as type1, 
    t2.type_name as type2
from katachi k, m_type t1, m_type t2
where k.type1=t1.id and (k.type2=t2.id or k.type2 is null);
```

now when it comes to katachi with two types it shows every element in m_type table, I want it just to display null

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UNION` of two queries, one for the case where both FKs are filled in, the other for the case of one FK.

```
SELECT k.name, t1.type_name AS type1, t2.type_name AS t2
FROM katachi AS k
JOIN m_type AS t1 ON k.type1 = t1.id
JOIN m_type AS t2 ON k.type2 = t2.id
UNION ALL
SELECT k.name, t.type_name AS type1, NULL AS type2
FROM katachi AS k
JOIN m_type AS t ON k.type1 = t.id
WHERE k.type2 IS NULL
```